# Event between custom component and page in Nativescript

Tags: javascript, events, data-binding, components, nativescript

In my NativeScript (JS/Core) app I have a custom component with a button inside:

**mycomp.xml**

```xml
<!-- mycomp.xml -->
<StackLayout loaded="onLoaded">
  <Button text="{{ label }}" tap="onTap" />
  ...
</StackLayout>
```

**mycomp.js**

```js
/* mycomp.js */
function onLoaded(args) {
    const obj = args.object;
    obj.bindingContext = {
        label: obj.label
    };
}

function onTap(args) {
    console.log('comp button tap'); // fired
}
```

**page.xml**

```xml
<!-- page.xml -->
<Page xmlns:mycomp="components/mycomp" xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
...
<mycomp:mycomp label="Test" tap="onButtonTap" />
...
</Page>
```

**page.js**

```js
/* page.js */
exports.onButtonTap = function(args) {
  console.log('Button Tap'); // not fired
}
```

How can I pass the tap event inside the component to the page event "onButtonTap"?

Comment: The custom component has its own viewmodel or its inheriting the parents? If it's inheriting the parents you don't have to specifically pass anything, just define the callback function in parent page's view model and bind it to tap event in the component.

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=dfavSH

Comment: Thank you very much Manoj and Nick lliev. This helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Because I wanted to use my component multiple times on different pages, I worked out this solution with the help of the comments here.

```js
// home-view-model.js
const fromObject = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable").fromObject;
function createViewModel() {
    var viewModel = fromObject({
        compdata: {
            foo: "bar",
            ontap: function(args) {
                console.log('button tap');
            }
        }
    });

    return viewModel;
}

exports.createViewModel = createViewModel;
```

```xml
<!-- home-page.xml -->
<Page xmlns:mycomp="components/mycomp" xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
...
<mycomp:mycomp compdata="compdata" />
...
</Page>
```

```js
// mycomp.js
const fromObject = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable").fromObject;
function onLoaded(args) {
    const obj = args.object;
    obj.bindingContext = fromObject(obj.compdata);
}
```

```xml
<!-- mycomp.xml -->
<StackLayout loaded="onLoaded">
  <Button text="{{ foo }}" tap="{{ ontap }}" />
  ...
</StackLayout>
```